# JavaScript .toString() default value

Tags: javascript, function, tostring

I am trying to write a function that will take another function as an argument (we can assume that the other function's toString method will always be overridden ti return a custom value) and return the function's original toString value.

```
     function foo () {} 
     foo.toString = function () {
     return 'abc';    }
```

How do I revert the function's toString method so it will return "function foo () {} " again?

Answer (score 3):

Since `toString` is a prototype property, when you `delete` it, it reverts to the default:

```js
function foo () {} 

foo.toString = function () {
     return 'abc';    
}

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(String(foo),0,3));

delete foo.toString

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(String(foo),0,3));
```